# How to identify devices connected to serial port

Tags: 14.04, serial-port

- I have an ADLINK embedded box computer
- Ubuntu 14.04 is installed.
- I have two devices connected to serial ports of ADLINK box (COM1 RS-232 and HSUART RS-485).

How can I check what device is connected to which serial port on Ubuntu 14.04? Also do I have to configure serial ports on Ubuntu 14.04?.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out information about your serial ports, you can run the following command:

```
dmesg | egrep --color 'serial|ttyS'
```

To report or set the configuration information associated with a serial port, you can run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install setserial
setserial -g /dev/ttyS[0123]
```

More information about this: [Site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-setup-serial-console-on-debian-linux/)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link. Link has information on UART port configuration. But I couldn't find about configuring COM port. Can you please help me

Comment: See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SerialConsoleHowto